# Binding an Array through multiple Views in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm stuck with this problem. I've the following struct that builds a List from a @Binding Array

```
struct AppleList: View {

    @Binding var apples: [Apple]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(apples) { apple  in
                    NavigationLink(destination: AppleDetail(apple: $apple)) {
                        AppleRow(apple: apple)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppleDetail has an edit button that switches between AppleSummary and AppleEditor, so here the apple will be modified.

```
struct AppleDetail: View {

    @Binding var apple: Apple

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

AppleRow doesn't need to modify apple.

```
struct AppleRow: View {

    var apple: Apple

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is in the ForEach loop: how can make a binding element from a binding array of elements that when they will be modified will send the modification to the parent of AppleList?

Answer (score -1):

Solution was quite simple:

```
ForEach(apples.indices) { idx in
    NavigationLink(destination: AppleDetail(transaction: self.$apples[idx])) {
        AppleRow(transaction: apples[idx])
    }
}
```

Comment: ForEach crashes if you use indices instead of Identifiable structs

Comment: @Lorenzo, how has this solution worked out over time? Would you mind sharing more code from the AppleDetail and AppleEditor views, so I can see how you did the binding in those cases?